# Predicate для поиска с апострофом

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как задать предикат, чтобы поиск осуществлялся с апострофом?

Мой код:
`let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText)`

Например мне надо найти `Daniel's`, я пишу `Daniels`, и ничего не найдено. Находит только если написать `Daniel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно несколько грязно, но попробуйте так:

```
let searchAllText = searchText.characters.map({"*\($0)"}).joined()
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name like[cd] '\(searchAllText)*'")
```

---

UPD Думал только текст.

Для начала нужно решить что делать с апострофом + можно сделать чтоб не экранировать(ну по сути вернуть что и было у Вас). Первый вариант - не обращать особо внимание:

```
let searchAllText = searchText.characters.map({"*\($0)"}).joined() + "*"
//либо вариант 2 - вообще исключить его
//let searchAllText = searchText.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "").characters.map({"*\($0)"}).joined() + "*"
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name like[cd] %@", searchAllText)
```

Ну и третий вариант - если пользователь поставил апостроф, то не искать между всеми буквами его:

```
var searchAllText: String
if searchText.contains("'") {
    searchAllText = "*\(searchText)*"
} else {
    searchAllText = "\(searchText.characters.map({"*\($0)"}).joined())*" //пусть уже в одном стиле формирование строки
}
```

Comment: проблема возникает если пользователь сам добавит апостроф. Тогда приложение падает =(

Comment: @VitaliEller обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Использовал второй вариант, работает превосходно =)